# How do I retrieve an item from a PHP private Object Array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, private

I've searched everywhere, IPB forums, google, everywhere.

I couldn't find any documentation from IPB/IP.Nexus forums because they don't have any, it's encrypted with Zend.

What I was trying to do was retrieve the item, "quantity" from an private Object Array within the function it's passed to.

This is the php file.

```
<?php 
class custom_actions_ibeconomy
{
        /**
         * Item Purchased (run before onPurchaseGenerated)
         *
         * @param       array   The member purchasing
         * @param       array   Package data (combined array with row from nexus_packages and nexus_packages_*, depending on the package type)
         * @param       invoice Invoice Model
         * @return      void
         */
        public function onPaid( $member, $package, $invoice )
        {

        }

        /**
         * Purchase record generated (run after onPaid)
         *
         * @param       array   The member purchasing
         * @param       array   Package data (combined array with row from nexus_packages and nexus_packages_*, depending on the package type)
         * @param       invoice Invoice Model
         * @param       array   Row from nexus_purchases [since Nexus 1.5]
         * @return      void
         */
        public function onPurchaseGenerated( $member, $package, $invoice, $purchase )
        {
        #What package have we purchased here?
        switch($package['p_id']) {
                        case 3: // 500 HLcoins
                                $value = 500;
                                break;
                        case 4: // 1000 HLcoins
                                $value = 1000;
                                break;

                        default: //Neither? 0 HLcoins.
                                $value = 0;
                                break;;
                }       
        #Find current members HLcoins?           
        $amount = $this->$invoice->quantity * $value;

        #execute points
        ipsRegistry::DB()->update( 'pfields_content', 'eco_points=eco_points+'.$amount, 'member_id=' . $member['member_id'] , true, true );   
        }

        /**
         * Purchase Renewed, but was still active anyway
         *
         * @param       array   The member renewing
         * @param       array   Package data (combined array with row from nexus_packages and nexus_packages_*, depending on the package type)
         * @param       invoice Invoice Model
         * @param       array   The row from nexus_purchases [since Nexus 1.5]
         * @return      void
         */
        public function onRenew( $member, $package, $invoice, $purchase )
        {

        }        

        /**
         * Purchase Renewed after had expired
         *
         * @param       array                   The member renewing
         * @param       array                   Package data (combined array with row from nexus_packages and nexus_packages_*, depending on the package type)
         * @param       invoice|null    Invoice Model [May not be set if manually reactivating]
         * @param       array                   The row from nexus_purchases [since Nexus 1.5]
         * @return      void
         */
        public function onReactivate( $member, $package, $invoice, $purchase )
        {

        }

        /**
         * Purchase Expired
         *
         * @param       array                   The member the purchase belongs to
         * @param       array                   Package data (combined array with row from nexus_packages and nexus_packages_*, depending on the package type)
         * @param       invoice|null    Will usually be null. If the purchase is expiring because the invoice which previously renewed it is now being marked unpaid, the invoice object will be passed.
         * @param       array                   The row from nexus_purchases [since Nexus 1.5]
         * @return      void
         */
        public function onExpire( $member, $package, $invoice, $purchase )
        {

        }

        /**
         * Purchase Cancelled or Deleted
         *
         * @param       array                   The member the purchase belongs to
         * @param       array                   Package data (combined array with row from nexus_packages and nexus_packages_*, depending on the package type)
         * @param       invoice|null    Will usually be null. If the purchase is being cancelled because the invoice which was used to purchase it it is now being marked unpaid, the invoice object will be passed.
         * @param       array                   The row from nexus_purchases [since Nexus 1.5]
         * @return      void
         */
        public function onCancel( $member, $package, $invoice, $purchase )
        {

        }

        /**
         * Purchase is transferred to another member
         *
         * @param       array           Old owner
         * @param       array           Package data (combined array with row from nexus_packages and nexus_packages_*, depending on the package type)
         * @param       array           The row from nexus_purchases
         * @param       customer        New owner
         * @return      void
         */
        public function onTransfer( $oldOwner, $package, $purchase, $newOwner )
        {

        }

        /**
         * Purchase is upgraded/downgraded
         *
         * @param       array           The member the purchase belongs to
         * @param       array           Old package data (combined array with row from nexus_packages and nexus_packages_*, depending on the package type)
         * @param       array           The row from nexus_purchases
         * @param       package         New package object
         * @return      void
         */
        public function onchange( $member, $oldPackage, $purchase, $newPackage )
        {

        }

        /**
         * Purchases' parent purchase is changed
         *
         * @param       array                   The member the purchase belongs to
         * @param       array                   Package data (combined array with row from nexus_packages and nexus_packages_*, depending on the package type)
         * @param       array                   The row from nexus_purchases
         * @param       array|null        The previous parent (may be null if had no parent previously)
         * @param       array|null        The new parent (may be null if was previously associated and now not)
         * @return      void
         */
        public function onAssociate( $member, $package, $purchase, $oldParent, $newParent )
        {

        }

}
?>
```

However it returns nothing.

I've printed the array out and it's listed as private, but its within the function so I should be able to retrieve it, I just don't know how and I need your help.

```
invoice Object
(
    [data:private] => Array
    (
    [i_status] => pend
    [i_title] => 500 HLCoins , 500 HLCoins x8
    [i_member] => 1
    [i_items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
    [act] => new
    [app] => nexus
    [type] => product
    [cost] => 0
    [tax] => 0
    [renew_term] => 0
    [renew_units] =>
    [renew_cost] => 0
    [quantity] => 1
    [physical] =>
    [shipping] => Array
        (
            )
        [weight] => 0
        [itemName] => 500 HLCoins
        [itemID] => 3
        [cfields] => Array
(
)
[extra] =>
[opt_id] => 0
[associated] =>
[assocBought] =>
[groupRenewals] => 0
[methods] => Array
(
)
[k] => 0
[_tax] => 0
)
[1] => Array
(
[act] => new
[app] => nexus
[type] => product
[cost] => 0
[tax] => 0
[renew_term] => 0
[renew_units] =>
[renew_cost] => 0
[quantity] => 8
[physical] =>
[shipping] => Array
(
)
[weight] => 0
[itemName] => 500 HLCoins
[itemID] => 3
[cfields] => Array
(
)
[opt_id] => 0
[groupRenewals] => 0
[methods] => Array
(
)
[_tax] => 0
)
)
[i_total] => 0
[i_date] => 1347217384
[i_return_uri] =>
[i_paid] => 0
[i_status_extra] => a:1:{s:4:"type";s:4:"zero";}
[i_discount] => 0
[i_temp] =>
[i_ordersteps] => 0
[i_noreminder] => 1
[i_renewal_ids] => Array
(
)
[i_po] =>
[i_notes] =>
[i_shipaddress] =>
[i_id] => 229
)
[customer:private] => customer Object
(
[data] => Array
(
[member_id] => 1
[name] => Administrator
[member_group_id] => 4
[email] => honlegends@gmail.com
[joined] => 1346519183
[ip_address] => 108.251.14.208
[posts] => 19
[title] => Administrator
[allow_admin_mails] => 0
[time_offset] => -8
[skin] => 5
[warn_level] => 0
[warn_lastwarn] => 0
[language] => 1
[last_post] => 1347048210
[restrict_post] =>
[view_sigs] => 1
[view_img] => 1
[bday_day] => 0
[bday_month] => 0
[bday_year] => 0
[msg_count_new] => 0
[msg_count_total] => 1
[msg_count_reset] => 0
[msg_show_notification] => 1
[misc] =>
[last_visit] => 1347174074
[last_activity] => 1347217377
[dst_in_use] => 1
[coppa_user] => 0
[mod_posts] =>
[auto_track] =>
[temp_ban] => 0
[login_anonymous] => 0&1
[ignored_users] => a:0:{}
[mgroup_others] => 7
[org_perm_id] => ,,,,,8,
[member_login_key] => 341ebfc939f1c5acb5dbe8b9a6819b21
[member_login_key_expire] => 1347820877
[has_blog] =>
[blogs_recache] =>
[has_gallery] => 0
[members_auto_dst] => 1
[members_display_name] => PAPA_bert
[members_seo_name] => papa-bert
[members_created_remote] => 0
[members_cache] => a:7:{s:11:"report_temp";a:0:{}s:19:"report_last_updated";i:1347139096;s:10:"report_num";s:1:"0";s:13:"msgAlertReset";i:1346520781;s:13:"notifications";a:19:{s:13:"report_center";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:11:"new_comment";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:11:"post_quoted";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:0:{}}s:9:"new_likes";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"inline";}}s:15:"followed_topics";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:15:"followed_forums";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:22:"followed_topics_digest";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:22:"followed_forums_digest";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:15:"profile_comment";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"inline";}}s:14:"friend_request";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"inline";}}s:22:"friend_request_approve";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"inline";}}s:19:"new_private_message";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:21:"reply_private_message";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:22:"invite_private_message";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:17:"reply_your_status";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:0:{}}s:16:"reply_any_status";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:0:{}}s:20:"friend_status_update";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:0:{}}s:7:"warning";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}}s:12:"warning_mods";a:1:{s:8:"selected";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"inline";}}}s:23:"show_notification_popup";i:0;s:7:"friends";a:1:{i:11;s:1:"1";}}
[members_disable_pm] => 0
[members_l_display_name] => papa_bert
[members_l_username] => administrator
[failed_logins] =>
[failed_login_count] => 0
[members_profile_views] => 575
[members_pass_hash] => cf407e695cc8d14e0a7079c8e0e1f4b4
[members_pass_salt] => ]s:%5
[member_banned] => 0
[member_uploader] => flash
[members_bitoptions] => 0
[fb_uid] => 0
[fb_emailhash] =>
[fb_lastsync] => 0
[members_day_posts] => 0,0
[live_id] =>
[twitter_id] =>
[twitter_token] =>
[twitter_secret] =>
[notification_cnt] => 0
[tc_lastsync] => 0
[fb_session] =>
[fb_token] =>
[ips_mobile_token] =>
[unacknowledged_warnings] =>
[feedb_percent] => -1
[feedb_pos] => 0
[feedb_neg] => 0
[feedb_neu] => 0
[sospromote_vip] => 0
[sospromote_vip_eterno] => 0
[sospromote_vip_g_origem] => 0
                    [sospromote_vip_dias] => 0
                    [sospromote_vip_secondary] => 0
                    [sospromote_vip_removesecondary] => 0
                    [sub_end] => 0
                    [subs_pkg_chosen] => 0
                    [cm_credits] => 0
                    [cm_reg] => 0
                    [referred_by] => 0
                    [cm_no_sev] => 0
                    [cim_profile_id] => 
                    [cim_payment_id] => 0
                    [cim_method] => 0
                    [cm_return_group] => 0
                    [my_member_id] => 1
                    [pp_member_id] => 1
                    [pp_last_visitors] => a:2:{i:1346978590;i:7;i:1346536186;i:2;}
                    [pp_rating_hits] => 0
                    [pp_rating_value] => 0
                    [pp_rating_real] => 0
                    [pp_main_photo] => http://www.honlegends.com/community/uploads/profile/photo-1.jpg?_r=1347002709
                    [pp_main_width] => 170
                    [pp_main_height] => 125
                    [pp_thumb_photo] => http://www.honlegends.com/community/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-1.jpg?_r=1347002709
                    [pp_thumb_width] => 100
                    [pp_thumb_height] => 100
                    [pp_setting_moderate_comments] => 0
                    [pp_setting_moderate_friends] => 0
                    [pp_setting_count_friends] => 1
                    [pp_setting_count_comments] => 1
                    [pp_setting_count_visitors] => 1
                    [pp_about_me] => 
                    [pp_reputation_points] => 1
                    [pp_gravatar] => 
                    [pp_photo_type] => custom
                    [signature] => [center][img]http://tomeisopa.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/snooze-snorlax.png[/img][/center]
                    [avatar_location] => 
                    [avatar_size] => 0
                    [avatar_type] => 
                    [pconversation_filters] => 
                    [fb_photo] => 
                    [fb_photo_thumb] => 
                    [fb_bwoptions] => 0
                    [tc_last_sid_import] => 0
                    [tc_photo] => 
                    [tc_bwoptions] => 0
                    [pp_customization] => 
                    [pp_profile_update] => 1347002709
                    [cache_content] => <p class='bbc_center'><span rel='lightbox'><img src='http://tomeisopa.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/snooze-snorlax.png' alt='Posted Image' class='bbc_img' /></span></p>
                    [full] => 1
                    [_canBeIgnored] => 
                    [bw_is_spammer] => 0
                    [bw_from_sfs] => 0
                    [bw_vnc_type] => 0
                    [bw_forum_result_type] => 0
                    [bw_no_status_update] => 0
                    [bw_status_email_mine] => 0
                    [bw_status_email_all] => 0
                    [bw_disable_customization] => 0
                    [bw_local_password_set] => 0
                    [bw_disable_tagging] => 0
                    [bw_disable_prefixes] => 0
                    [bw_using_skin_gen] => 0
                    [bw_disable_gravatar] => 0
                    [_group_formatted] => <span style="color: #46c843; font-weight: bold; text-shadow: 0 0 .7em #59ff55;">Administrators</span>
                    [member_rank_img] => http://www.honlegends.com/community/public/style_extra/team_icons/admin.png
                    [member_rank_img_i] => img
                    [show_warn] => 1
                    [custom_fields] => 
                    [_has_photo] => 1
                    [pp_small_photo] => http://www.honlegends.com/community/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-1.jpg?_r=1347002709
                    [pp_small_width] => 50
                    [pp_small_height] => 50
                    [pp_mini_photo] => http://www.honlegends.com/community/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-1.jpg?_r=1347002709
                    [pp_mini_width] => 25
                    [pp_mini_height] => 25
                    [_online] => 1
                    [_last_active] => Today, 12:02 PM
                    [_pp_rating_real] => 0
                    [members_display_name_formatted] => <span style="color: #46c843; font-weight: bold; text-shadow: 0 0 .7em #59ff55;">PAPA_bert</span>
                    [members_display_name_short] => PAPA_bert
                    [author_reputation] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Neutral
                            [image] => 
                        )

                    [member_title] => Administrator
                    [cm_first_name] => Albert
                    [cm_last_name] => Yang
                    [cm_address_1] => 2919 Warwick Ave
                    [cm_address_2] => 
                    [cm_city] => Los Angeles
                    [cm_state] => CA
                    [cm_zip] => 90032
                    [cm_country] => US
                    [cm_phone] => 3233160892
                    [_name] => Albert Yang
                )

            [cardhandler:private] => 
        )

    [takeAction] => 1
)
```

Comment: You could use the Reflexion API but I discourage you to try to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($object);
$objectStr = ob_get_clean();
```

and then use string functions to get the value - similar to:

```
$qPos = strpos($objectStr,"quantity",0);
$value = substring($objectStr$qPos+SOMEVALUE,$qPOS+SOMEVALUE+LENGTH);
```

That's not a perfect answer and you'll have to tweak it.

As @abhi-beckert said,, however, it's bad form to do it and likely horrible for performance. Check the documentation and see if there's a different way.

You can't extend the class to do it - private aren't inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Private properties cannot be accessed. Only debugging tools like `var_dump()` can see them.

You should find the definition for the `invoice` class and add a new function to edit the property (assuming it doesn't have one already) or just change it to public.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the class, and create an accessor method (or "getter") to retrieve the value:

```
<?php
class YourClassName extends custom_actions_ibeconomy
{
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad. As @Philip Whitehouse says, private properties aren't inherited in extending classes, only public and protected properties are. D'oh!